# What is the default username for AWS AMI images for an Oracle Linux Server (ami-3f739c56)?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, amazon-ami

I've created a new instance of AMI Oracle Database 11.2.0.1 64-bit Standard Edition; ami-3f739c56 supplied by Oracle. I've tried to access the instance via SSH from my Windows 10 PC (also from my Mac) but I get the error "Server refused our key. Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-with-mic)". I've tried:

1. User IDs: root; oracle; admin; ec2-user
2. restarting the instance
3. rebuilding the key-pairs
4. Searching Stack Overflow for anything related to this type of problem (everything I've found is out of date by several years and seem to related only to Ubuntu)
5. searching Oracle's site
6. searching the Internet

The key-pair that I initially used is fine for my Ubuntu instance that I'm able to connect (User ID: admin).

Everything that I've found so far points to the problem being with me using the wrong default User ID but I don't have anything to tell me what the correct User ID should be.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Correction: I incorrectly stated that my Ubuntu instance was accessible via SSH. However, it's actually my "Debian" instance, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the AWS Marketplace, navigate to the AMI page
2. Click on the Usage tab
3. Click on View Usage Instructions
4. Note that if the vendor is clckwrk Ltd, then the user is clckwrk

(I did not find OP's "ami-3f739c56")

Answer (score 0):

1. check health of your AMI:

   - In the navigation pane, choose Instances, and select the instance.
   - Choose Actions, Instance Settings, Get System Log.
2. Write to AWS support.

In my experience there are very "stupid" mistakes:

- instance not allow ssh connection, check aws security groups and network acl
- you have a typo when you connect via ssh
- you have wrong permissions to the ssh key,
- or you use wrong ssh key )
- try -vvv parameters for ssh command, maybe you can see the erors

Answer (score 0):

The user 'root' worked for me. When I logged in for the first time using 'root' user, it walked me though the Oracle setup process.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem too. The username is: `clckwrk`